# MSQLi query doesn't delete data at specific time

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I want to delete data from table at specific time. For example at 15:00.

My code looks like this:

```
$time = date("H:i");
$timeToDel = date('H:i', strtotime("15:00"));

if($time == $timeToDel) {
    mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM table1");
    mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM table2");
}
```

There is that, when i open the page at 15:00, data from database will be deleted, but when I open the page at 15:01, data won't be deleted from database and they will be still visible on page.

Whole script is on hosting and not on my localhost.

Comment: add your database value format

Comment: what value do you mean?

Comment: how you are storing value in your database, add store data format

Comment: i'm not storing date in database, just few varchars and integers.

Comment: @Simi you might want to try changing your format strings to `H:i:00:00` to make sure that the seconds and milliseconds are the same, since they could be slightly different between the two. Have you tried using print_r to compare the two dates yourself?

Answer (score 2):

1. Mostly server time is different from local  time , So check server time and it's format.

Comment: I agree that this is most likely the issue. I believe that `strtotime` generates a UTC timestamp and won't do any timezone conversion unless a default timezone is set.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use cron job,Using cron job you can execute file with a specific time. you can learn it from here https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/cron-jobs/.

Comment: OP is not asking to run cron job, try to figure out solution for OP question only.